CMAKE автоматическая линковка
текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом
при удалении кеша Cmake приходится каждый раз прописывать заново пути к библиотекам, можно ли как то это автоматизировать в CMakeLists, что бы и cmake gui и qt creator подхватывал пути до библиотек и заголовочных файлов

например использовать директивы include_directories и link_directories cmake - почитайте доку
